# KVM with public IP for a VM

Tags: linux-networking, kvm-virtualization

I'm looking to build a VM using KVM/qemu in my dedicated server and assign to it one of the 2 Ip addresses I got assigned for my dedi. However, following this guide https://medium.com/techtalk-blog/kvm-with-public-ips-and-vnc-for-a-linux-vm-64c78a6c43e1 It mentiones that and I quote:

> If your IPs are not in the same subnet you will need to configure the host to perform routing, which is also not covered here.

And I'm unsure of how this "routing" would need to be done. Would really appreciate some advice on this. This guide is also rather old maybe this is not the best way to do what I want.

Comment: Or would it be possible to create a bridge with the second public IP and assign the vm to it? The thing is I need the server to be directly reachable over the internet on a certain port.

Comment: Usually the host provider provides a documentation. Each provider has specific rules that must be followed to get the expected result. You should provide a link from your provider about this.